# populate tooltip value in d3 using attributes / scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am trying to add some tooltips to some D3 rect elements, however having some trouble accessing attributes of the element to populate the tooltip value.

The following fiddle demonstrates this problem, 
http://jsfiddle.net/7Df2r/3/

My idea would be to use the x attribute of the object and some sort of inverse scale in D3 to back out the proper value, however my attempts at :

```
.text(d.attr("x"));
```

or

```
.text(d.properties.x);
```

in the mouseover function are coming up undefined, plus I believe this will be the x coordinate when really I want the x scale inverse of that attribute to match what the user will see on the chart.

Any thoughts on best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `this`, instead of `d`.

Comment: The general pattern would be to use a function, e.g. `.text(function(d) { return d.x; })`, however, in your jsfiddle no data is bound to the element, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`, instead of `d`:

`.text(this.getAttribute("height")/30);`

Note that `30` is the height in pixels corresponding to a value of `1` in the x axis.

It would be much better if you could programmatically get that value.

Please, [see a working fiddle whith this solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/DWagg/).